# Connection Refused while Runing Laravel Dusk with Laravel Sail

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-dusk, laravel-sail

I'm trying to use Laravel Dusk integrated with Laravel Sail as described in: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#laravel-dusk

I'm facing some problems when it comes to make this work:

- If a use, a .env.dusk or .env.dusk.local file and run the tests using 'sail dusk', I get a CONNECTION REFUSED ERROR (More details below)
- If a use, for example, a .env.testing to setup ENV variables and run 'sail dusk --env=testing', the CONNECTION REFUSED ERROR disappear but app continues to use the default .env file while the dusk tests uses the .env.testing, leading to a lot of bugs.

#### docker-compose.yml

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - selenium
    selenium:
        image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
        volumes:
            - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
        networks:
            - sail
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ['CMD', 'mysqladmin', 'ping']
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ['CMD', 'redis-cli', 'ping']
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
```

#### .env.dusk

```
APP_NAME="Plataforma Brasileira SE"
APP_URL="http://plataformabrasileira-se.test"
APP_ENV=testing
APP_KEY=base64:bc0IGvpHb/ymQD7vUTJa60qhG7T2dtozC6urijChcbo=
DB_CONNECTION=dusk
MAIL_MAILER=array
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=array
TELESCOPE_ENABLED=false
```

#### database.php

```
...
'dusk' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => database_path('database.sqlite'),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
 ],
 ...
```

#### DuskTestCase.php

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Laravel\Dusk\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class DuskTestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;

    /**
     * Prepare for Dusk test execution.
     *
     * @beforeClass
     * @return void
     */
    public static function prepare()
    {
        if (! static::runningInSail()) {
            static::startChromeDriver();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the RemoteWebDriver instance.
     *
     * @return \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver
     */
    protected function driver()
    {
        $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--headless',
            '--window-size=1920,1080',
        ]);

        return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            $_ENV['DUSK_DRIVER_URL'] ?? 'http://localhost:9515',
            DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
                ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
            )
        );
    }
}
```

When I run *'sail dusk'*, I get the following error:

```
1) Tests\Browser\LoginTest::test_user_cannot_login_with_invalid_data
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownErrorException: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
  (Session info: headless chrome=88.0.4324.96)

/var/www/html/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Exception/WebDriverException.php:139
/var/www/html/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:371
/var/www/html/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:612
/var/www/html/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteExecuteMethod.php:27
/var/www/html/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/WebDriverNavigation.php:41
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Browser.php:153
/var/www/html/tests/Browser/LoginTest.php:18
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:68
/var/www/html/tests/Browser/LoginTest.php:28
```

Comment: So thorough—well asked, especially in the SO universe!

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
APP_URL=http://laravel.test
```

since the test is run in selenium docker, this references back to your laravel docker container.

Comment: I tried this before the higher voted answer and it worked—no need to extra work! I didn't have to touch a *DUSK_DRIVER_URL*. I just copied my `.env` to `.env.dusk.local` and then changed the *DB_HOST* to `testing` (already created by sail) and the *APP_URL* from `http://localhost` to `http://laravel.test` then ran the test with `sail dusk` —beautiful!

Answer (score 3):

The real issue seems to be usage of containers and configuration has to match it. Current solution assumes that the name of the container running Laravel is still set to **laravel.test**.

Your `.env.dusk.local` file would need to contain an additional environment variable named **DUSK_DRIVER_URL** with value of `http://selenium:4444`. If you inspect the selenium container, then it will have two ports mentioned, with both of those not bound: `4444` and `5900`. It seems that the first one is the one running the `RemoteWebDriver`.

The other variable is **APP_URL** that should be set to `http://laravel.test`, at least if the default service container name has not been changed.

Those two changes should allow for the Dusk tests to be running as they were supposed to.

I've found the second part of the puzzle from an accepted comment for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65569147/laravel-sail-dusk-selenium-connection-refused) discussion thread.